# Slot was skipped. But ledger tool command says it's present. How to fix?

Tags: missing

This slot is present in other 3 nodes I'm running and has no errors. Only this node is giving errors for this block and 1000s of other blocks.

The ledger tool shows the slot is present.

```
solana@us-west1-20:/data/solana-ledger$ solana-ledger-tool -l . slot 221650090
[2023-10-06T09:52:51.244003441Z INFO  solana_ledger_tool] solana-ledger-tool 1.16.14 (src:c932953e; feat:4033350765, client:SolanaLabs)
[2023-10-06T09:52:51.244098510Z INFO  solana_ledger::blockstore] Maximum open file descriptors: 1000000
[2023-10-06T09:52:51.244102404Z INFO  solana_ledger::blockstore] Opening database at "/data/solana-ledger/rocksdb"
[2023-10-06T09:52:51.248727142Z INFO  solana_ledger::blockstore_db] Opening Rocks with secondary (read only) access at: "/data/solana-ledger/rocksdb/solana-secondary"
[2023-10-06T09:52:51.248738214Z INFO  solana_ledger::blockstore_db] This secondary access could temporarily degrade other accesses, such as by solana-validator
[2023-10-06T09:54:48.626724520Z INFO  solana_ledger::blockstore_db] Rocks's automatic compactions are disabled due to Secondary access
[2023-10-06T09:54:48.627296091Z INFO  solana_ledger::blockstore] "/data/solana-ledger/rocksdb" open took 117.4s

Slot 221650090

[2023-10-06T09:54:49.712119400Z INFO  solana_ledger_tool] ledger tool took 118.5s
```

But when I query, I get the following error.

```
solana@us-west1-20:/data/solana-ledger$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"jsonrpc": "2.0","id":1,"method":"getBlock","params":[221650090, {"maxSupportedTransactionVersion": 0}]}' localhost:8899
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32007,"message":"Slot 221650090 was skipped, or missing due to ledger jump to recent snapshot"},"id":1}
solana@us-west1-20:/data/solana-ledger$
```

Anyway to fix?

I tried the repair command for the whole range reported missing in queries.

```
solana-ledger-tool -l /data/solana-ledger/ repair-roots --before 221675707 --until 221646988
```

Didn't work. Got,

```
No missing roots found in range
```

If I can rewind the chain like geth, that would be great.

```
debug.setHead(block)
```

anway to do that?

Comment: Worth noting that while `slot` and `block` are closely related, they are different things. A `slot` is a period of time where a `block` *may* be produced, but it's not guaranteed. `Slots` that don't produce `blocks` are `skipped-slots`. So when the ledger tools reports that a `slot` exists, it might not mean that it produced a `block`, just that the ledger contains activity for that `slot`.

Comment: Forgot to mention that slot contains a block. Other nodes confirms this. Will update the question.

Answer (score 0):

> Slot 221650090

That output is not actually showing the slot as present; there would be more output if the slot were present. For example, here is the output from a random slot I picked on my ledger:

```
$ solana-ledger-tool slot 223505826 --ledger ~/ledger/
...

Slot 223505826
  num_shreds: 659, parent_slot: Some(223505825), next_slots: [223505827], num_entries: 206, is_full: true
```

Also, you should confirm that the slot itself should be in the ledger by running the `bounds` subcommand:

```
$ solana-ledger-tool bounds --ledger ~/ledger/
...

Ledger has data for 291046 slots 223211323 to 223505858
  with 287976 rooted slots from 223211323 to 223505826
  and 32 slots past the last root
```